# Sequence error while inserting multiple rows using "WITH" clause

Tags: oracle, sequence

```
  INSERT INTO items (
    item_id, psuedo_row_flag, item_hierarchy_level, 'some other cols...'  
  )
  WITH s_item_group
  AS 
    (
      SELECT hier_level, 'some other cols...'   FROM ITEM_GROUPS   
    )
    SELECT MY_SQL.nextval, 'N', hier_level FROM s_item_group
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MY_SQL.nextval, 'Y', hier_level + 1 FROM s_item_group;
```

Basically I want to insert two set of rows. One indicates an actual row and another one is a pseudo row. The pseudo row will have 
psuedo_row_flag set to 'Y' and its hierarchy level as +1 of its corresponding actual row's hierarchy_level.

When I try this query I am getting the error "Sequence number not allowed here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use sequences in `UNION`'ed queries.

Try this:

```
INSERT
INTO    items
WITH    s_items_group AS (...)
SELECT  my_sql.nextval, flag, hier_level
FROM    (
        SELECT  'N' flag, hier_level
        FROM    s_items_group
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Y' flag, hier_level + 1
        FROM    s_items_group
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap your UNION ALL inside another subquery:

```
 INSERT INTO items
   (item_id,
    psuedo_row_flag,
    item_hierarchy_level)
   WITH s_item_group AS
    (SELECT hier_level
       FROM ITEM_GROUPS)
   select my_sql.nextval as item_id,
          psuedo_row_flag,
          hier_level
     from (SELECT 'N' psuedo_row_flag,
                  hier_level
             FROM s_item_group
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Y' psuedo_row_flag,
                  hier_level + 1
             FROM s_item_group)
```

And BTW, you might want fix the spelling of psuedo_row_flag :-)

Answer (score 0):

For this case, where you want to insert two rows for every row projected from a query, have a look instead at using multitable inserts. Sequences are a bit problematic, but you can populate that column with a trigger.